# How to use a switch statement to compare references

Tags: c#

I am trying to match references to fields in my struct, but I am not sure how I do it as a case setup rather than if statements.

This is the general idea I have done with if statements:

```
public struct Test
{
   // MyObject is a class
   public MyObject A;
   public MyObject B;
   public MyObject C;

   public bool Distance(MyObject obj, out float distance){
        distance = float.PositiveInfinity;
        if(A == obj){
         distance = DistanceFrom(A);
         return true;
        }
        if(B == obj){
         distance = DistanceFrom(B);
         return true;
        }
        if(C == obj){
         distance = DistanceFrom(C); 
         return true;
        }
        //object does not relate to this struct so return false
        return false;
   }
}
```

There is more than 3 in my actual struct (24 in total), but I am wondering how I might be able to do this comparison via a case statement instead, since it would be a lot cleaner than lots of if statements. Also, I don't wish to use a list of my 24 references and thus a simple for loop to run through it, as I would end up with my structs allocating to heap.

Is it possible to do a switch comparing references? I know how to compare by object type, but not if they are referencing the exact same object. Or is if statements my only option here?

Comment: This seems like a design issue here. Is this your real code?

Comment: It looks like you could do a single `if` as in `if(A == obj || B == obj || C == obj)`.

Comment: It's not my real code as my actual code is like 300 lines and without context its even more difficult to decipher what i am aiming to do, it does a bunch of things so i made a simplified example. But one thing i do have is lots of if statements checking if the object is one of the objects that belongs to the structs. That i thought a case statement would make it easier to write and more optimised too.

Comment: Can you please also show your real code? I'd like to understand how accurate your simplified example is.

Comment: case may be more clear, but using collections maybe even more.

Comment: Collections ends up allocating on the heap so can't do that @LeiYang

Comment: what's the matter of heap or stack, does it make any performance difference to you?

Comment: Who said it doesn't make a performance difference?

Comment: @Enigmativity its not very, i'm just asking if its possible to make a switch setup by comparing references. Not so much about how i approach my design for my project

Comment: A solution using collections is probably better.

Comment: Again no heap allocations for this. I need to run this on stack for high performance.

Comment: I guess i'll stick to many `if` statements for now if theres no alternative, its ugly and clunky but it works.

Comment: The whole *"stack heap thing"* and *"not wanting to use a collection"* logic is possibly flawed.

Comment: Not really i don't like the idea of generating lists every time i create these structs and destroy them every frame =/ Would prefer them to be small packets that i can throw away without too much worry.

Comment: @WDUK - Not liking something is ok once you have benchmarks to prove some sort of deficiency.

Comment: @Enigmativity not about liking, i need to take advantage of struct performance with the compiler and some memory management. But its besides the point im not here to go into the depths of explaining my project and my needs. For that i'll go to code review.

Comment: @WDUK - You did say "i don't ***like*** the idea of generating lists"

Comment: Yes and that suggestion really has nothing to do with the question, i was asking about switch statements. If i need suggestions on how to design my code again i'll ask on code review stack exchange. I don't like the idea of generating lists because that means im generating data on the heap every frame - not something i care to do for high performance on a hot path. Especially when they only last a few frames at most.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I agree with commenters that you might have a design issue, you can use a `when` filter with a `switch`.

```
public bool Distance(object obj, out float distance)
{
    switch (obj)
    {
        case var _ when ReferenceEquals(obj, A):
            distance = DistanceFrom(A);
            return true;
        case var _ when ReferenceEquals(obj, B):
            distance = DistanceFrom(B);
            return true;
        case var _ when ReferenceEquals(obj, C):
            distance = DistanceFrom(C);
            return true;
        default:
            distance = float.PositiveInfinity;
            return false;
    }
}
```

I know it looks a bit weird, but the `var _` is a discard and says you don't care about the value of `obj` (at least in the `case` itself, but you can still use `obj` in the `when`.

You stated you want to compare references. That is what `ReferenceEquals` does. If you don't want that, you can use `==` or whatever you deem equality means.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to read the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#the-case-statement-and-the-when-clause), this is the example to use a switch case with `when` clause:

```
public struct Test
{
   // MyObject is a class
   public MyObject A;
   public MyObject B;
   public MyObject C;

   public bool Distance(MyObject obj, out float distance){
        distance = float.PositiveInfinity;
        switch (obj){
            case MyObject o when  Object.ReferenceEquals(o,A):
              distance = DistanceFrom(A);
              return true;
            case MyObject o when  Object.ReferenceEquals(o,B):
              distance = DistanceFrom(B);
              return true;
            case MyObject o when  Object.ReferenceEquals(o,C):
              distance = DistanceFrom(C);
              return true;
            default:
              return false;
        }
        
   }
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: I mistake the example. But is in the same docs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest avoiding `switch` and just code this kind of thing directly.

Try this:

```
public bool Distance(object obj, out float distance)
{
    MyObject[] variables = new [] { A, B, C };
    MyObject match = variables.Where(x => ReferenceEquals(x, obj)).FirstOrDefault();
    bool result = match != null;
    distance = result ? DistanceFrom(match) : float.PositiveInfinity;
    return result;
}
```

Or perhaps slightly more flexibly:

```
public float? Distance(object obj)
{
    MyObject[] variables = new [] { A, B, C };
    MyObject match = variables.Where(x => ReferenceEquals(x, obj)).FirstOrDefault();
    return match != null ? (float?)DistanceFrom(match) : null;
}
```

Comment: you're using `Array`, and the OP says performance is low...

Comment: What does "performance is low" mean? And how does that relate to using an array?

Comment: please look at the comments below the question.

Comment: @LeiYang - But there's no evidence that this is an issue. It's also possible to move the array to a field and thus be at the same level of performance as individual fields. It's a moot point.